# VSCode debugger not binding breakpoints on Serverless Typescript app on Windows 10

Tags: typescript, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, serverless

As the title says, I can't seem to get the debugger to properly stop at breakpoints. My current configuration works with macs but no luck with Windows.

[image]

Here is my set up:

```
//project structure

.vscode/
├─ launch.json
.webpack/
├─ service/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ MyFunction/
│  │  │  ├─ handler.js/
│  │  │  ├─ handler.js.map/
src/
├─ MyFunction/
│  ├─ handler.ts/
node_modules/
package.json
serverless.yaml
tsconfig.json
build.tsconfig.json
```

```json
// launch.json

{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "DEBUG",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "console":"integratedTerminal",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "debug"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./~/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*",
        "webpack:///SOURCE_ROOT/*": "/*"
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

```yaml
//serverless.yaml

service: my-service

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-bundle

provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  timeout: 30
  versionFunctions: false
  memorySize: 128

custom:
  configFile: ./environmentVariables/${file(../environmentVariables/${opt:stage}.json):stageName, "development"}.json

functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: src/MyFunction/handler.myFunction
    events:
        - http:
            path: /myFunction
            method: get
            cors:
              origin: '*'
```

```
// build.tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es2017",
        "outDir": ".build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceRoot": "SOURCE_ROOT",
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts", "**/dist/**"]
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json

{
    "extends": "./build.tsconfig.json",
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/dist/**"]
}
```

```
// My debug script in package.json 

"debug": "node --lazy ./node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless offline --stage development --noPrependStageInUrl"
```

**Versions:**

- VSCode: 1.70.2
- Node: 14.19.1
- Serverless:

  - Framework Core: 3.24.1 (local) 3.24.1 (global)
  - Plugin: 6.2.2
  - SDK: 4.3.2
- Typescript: 4.5.5

I tried to set up a launch.json configuration with/without `outFiles`,

```
"outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/.webpack/service/src/**/*.js"]
```

I tried to use the global serverless command,

and nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated